# Ubuntu 18 upgrade to 20 breaks DNS

Tags: upgrade, dns, bind

Before I upgrade my Ubuntu 18 DNS server, BIND looks like this:

```
bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-03-04 15:49:57 EST; 1 weeks 1 days ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
 Main PID: 1496 (named)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4654)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bind9.service
           └─1496 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind
```

After the upgrade to 20 it looks like this:

```
named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-02-05 19:16:10 EST; 1s ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
    Process: 67132 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 67132 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And I get errors like these:

```
Refusing to operate on alias name or linked unit file bind9.service

Apr 01 19:26:46 server1 systemd[1]: named.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 01 19:26:46 server1 systemd[1]: Stopped BIND Domain Name Server.
Apr 01 19:26:46 server1 systemd[1]: named.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 01 19:26:46 server1 systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 01 19:26:46 server1 systemd[1]: Failed to start BIND Domain Name Server.
```

I didn't see anything in the logs that helped explain those errors. Is there some link I need to remove/re-create to make BIND work?

Comment: Since you say the versions are 18 and 20 you must be using Ubuntu Core products as that is a Ubuntu Core version number. If this is not correct please edit the question and correct. If it is correct add to the question that it is Ubuntu Core.

Comment: Use `journalctl -u bind9.service -n 50` to go back in your logs to before JournalD reports the "repeated too quickly" errors.  That will give yo uspecific error logs you can look at as to why you're failing.  Note a lot of things in older 18.04 BIND9 were chnaged before 20.04 BIND9 and some features deprecated so you have to keep that in mind with your upgrades when you look at the logs.

Comment: Tyvm Tom, I'm going to give the upgrade another try this upcoming weekend & hopefully that will help get me across the finish line. I will post an update afterward.

Comment: Finally got the upgrade to v20 to go successfully. First I had to put all the bind9 packages on hold so they wouldn't get updated (apt-mark hold bind9 and so on). That fixed the bind issue but it still wasn't resolving a lot of addresses until I commented out the IPv6 loopback entry in /etc/hosts (#::1). After that it worked fine.